# How to halt errGroup goroutines when the first error happens

Tags: go, goroutine

Let's say I have an `errgroup.Group` called `eg` that calls multiple goroutines with

```
eg.Go(func() error {
    // do work
})
```

then it waits as the following

```
if err := eg.Wait(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Let's say one goroutine (called by `eg.Go`) returns/has an error.

Is there a way to halt the execution of the whole `eg` goroutines as soon as that error happens?

Comment: [Create a group with context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup).  In the Go functions, exit when the [context is done](https://godoc.org/context#Context.Done).

Comment: That works (although I don't like passing the `cancel` function around), thanks!

Comment: There's no need to pass a cancel function around.  in fact, the cancel function is not exposed when `errgroup.WithContext` is used.

Comment: I was under the impression that I needed a `WithCancel` context. `context.Background()` seems to be enough. Thanks a lot.